# Properly Mock SqlConnection

Tags: c#, mocking, nunit, moq

I am trying to mock the below method,

```
public static object ExecuteGetObj(string query)
{
    object obj = null;

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

but it is not using the Mock SqlConnection instead it is trying to create the SqlConnection

```
 var command = new Mock<IDbCommand>();
 command.Setup(x => x.ExecuteScalar())
            .Verifiable();

 var connection = new Mock<IDbConnection>();
 connection
        .Setup(m => m.CreateCommand())
            .Returns(command.Object);

 connection.Object.Open();


 var obj = Common.ExecuteGetObj(sql);

 Assert.IsNull(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only mock either `abstract classes` or `interfaces`, so this is not going to work.

This code instantiates a `SqlConnection`, nowhere does it use the `Mock<IDbConnection>` you setup in the test. If you *absolutely do* want to unit test this code, the code itself needs to change; it needs to be passed a `IDbConnection` somehow, whether as a constructor argument (you need to have a non `static` class) or as an argument to the method itself, which you then can mock.

I would recommend *against* *unit testing* this method though, what problem are you trying to solve? It is generally considered [bad practice](https://dhh.dk/2014/test-induced-design-damage.html) to change code just to be able to test it. If you want to test this, you could look into integrating testing; if this code is part of an API you could (for instance) do end to end testing on that level.